# Relooping a function over its own output

Tags: r, function, loops, repeat

I have defined a function which I want to reapply to its own output multiple times. I tried

```
   replicate(1000,myfunction)
```

but realised that this is just applying my function to my initial input 1000 times, rather than applying my function to the new output each time. In effect what I desire is:

```
    function(function(...function(x_0)...))
```

1000 times over and being able to see the changes at each stage.

I have previous defined b as a certain vector of length 7.

```
        b_0=b
        C=matrix(0,7,1000)
        for(k in 1:1000){
            b_k=myfun(b_(k-1))
            }
        C=rbind(b_k)
        C
```

Is this the right idea behind what I want?

Comment: `?Recall` has an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop would work just fine here.

```
apply_fun_n_times <- function(input, fun, n){
  for(i in 1:n){
    input <- fun(input)
  }
  return(input)
}

addone <- function(x){x+1}

apply_fun_n_times(1, addone, 3)
```

which gives

```
> apply_fun_n_times(1, addone, 3)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure functional programming approach, use `Compose` from `functional` package:

```
library(functional)

f = Reduce(Compose, replicate(100, function(x) x+2))
#> f(2)
#[1] 202
```

But this solution does not work for too big `n` ! Very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Reduce for this. For example

```
add_two <- function(a) a+2
ignore_current <- function(f) function(a,b) f(a)

Reduce(ignore_current(add_two), 1:10, init=4)
# 24
```

Normally `Reduce` expects to iterate over a set of new values, but in this case I use `ignore_current` to drop the sequence value (`1:10`) so that parameter is just used to control the number of times we repeat the process. This is the same as

```
add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(add_two(4))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try a recursive function:

```
rec_func <- function(input, i=1000) {
                if (i == 0) {
                   return(input)
                } else {
                   input <- myfunc(input)
                   i <- i - 1
                   rec_func(input, i)
                }
            }
```

**example**

```
myfunc <- function(item) {item + 1}
> rec_func(1, i=1000)
[1] 1001
```

Comment: It would be a little bit safer to use `Recall` instead of `rec_func` inside the definition of your recursive function.

Comment: @Dason, actually, I'm editing my solution with Recall but the problem is, just placing `Recall` instead of the funciton name, I get "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?" with my example...

Comment: Are you replacing just the rec_func inside the function?  You'll want to keep the rec_func in the first line the same.

Comment: @Dason, I'm trying to replace the `rec_func` call that is inside the function,yes. A weird thing is that I tried to simplify my function (without Replace) and suppress the first 2 lines in the `else`and put `rec_func(myfunc(input), i-1)` and also got the error message...

Comment: I just tried it out.  It looks like it's more of an issue with R not liking really deep recursion.  This is a case where a loop would work just fine too.  Basically changing it to use Recall instead added a few layers of nesting and ended up making R give up as it thought it might be an infinite recursion.  You can see that the Recall version works by setting i to be something smaller.

Comment: @Dason, thanks for getting more deeply into this and for the explanation! And I guess you're right about the loop !